# Allure Report dashboard shows 0 Test suites

Tags: dashboard, allure

I running SoapUI tests with Jenkins-Maven build project. I updated the POM file to generate reports in Allure. The Jenkins Console output says Build Successful, Report Generation success. But Allure reports Dashboard says Testsuites 0 PASSED. Can you please help and let me know what is causing the issue. HEre is the POM file .

Thanks a lot !

========================

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapuiMavenTutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>SoapUI-Maven-Tutorial</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SoapUI-Maven-Tutorial</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-examples-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.6</aspectj.version>
        <allure.version>1.4.14</allure.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Added this junit adaptor-->
        <!--dependency>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency-->
        <!--added jdbc below in build element-->
    </dependencies>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <!--systemPath>C:\maven\ojdbc6.jar</systemPath-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        <groupId>com.smartbear</groupId>
        <artifactId>ready-api-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
<projectFile>C:\Gee-SoapUI-Projects-Backup\27Aug2015-POSBkup\May04-2015-Point of Sale.xml</projectFile>
                    <outputFolder>C:\Users\pulipge\.jenkins\jobs\SoapUI-PRO-Allure\workspace\allure-result
        </outputFolder>
    <reportFormat>xUNIT</reportFormat>
        <reportName>TestCase Report</reportName>
        <!--reportName>TestSuite Report</reportName-->
        <testSuite>ErrorCodes</testSuite>
        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
        <printReport>true</printReport>
        <exportAll>true</exportAll>
     <soapuiProperties>
         <property>
          <name>soapui.home</name>                 <value>C:\Users\pulipge\ReadyAPI-1.3.0\bin</value>
      </property>
    </soapuiProperties>
<properties> 
<property> 
<name>listener</name> <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value> 
  </property> 
   </properties>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
<excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
<plugins>

<plugin>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: POM seems to be ok. I think your Jenkins output should have a message that no XML files were found. That's why your report is empty.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Vania! Here is the console output:

Comment: Ready! API 1.3.0 TestCaseRunner Summary
-----------------------------
Time Taken: 4321ms
Total TestSuites: 1
Total TestCases: 1 (0 failed)
Total TestSteps: 3
Total Request Assertions: 2
Total Failed Assertions: 0
Total Exported Results: 3

12:20:11,249 INFO  [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Created report at file:/C:/Users/pulipge/.jenkins/jobs/SoapUI-PRO-Allure/workspace/allure-results/index.html
[JENKINS] Recording test results

Comment: INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:06 min

Comment: [INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-14T12:20:11-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 234M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\maven\bin\SoapUI-Maven-Tutorial\pom.xml to com.smartbear.soapuiMavenTutorial/SoapUI-Maven-Tutorial/1.0-SNAPSHOT/SoapUI-Maven-Tutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped

Comment: [WARNING] Could not delete temporary directory C:\Users\pulipge\AppData\Local\Temp\471503b4-63c1-4cd7-a286-3fba4b89ec11

Comment: Skipping installation of http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.3.3/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.zip to C:\maven: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.maven.apache.org
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\pulipge\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson8319835937795844910.bat

Comment: C:\Users\pulipge\.jenkins\jobs\SoapUI-PRO-Allure\workspace>cd C:\Users\pulipge\.jenkins\jobs\SoapUI-PRO-Allure\workspace\allure-results 

C:\Users\pulipge\.jenkins\jobs\SoapUI-PRO-Allure\workspace\allure-results>xcopy C:\Users\pulipge\temp\allure-results 
0 File(s) copied

Comment: C:\Users\pulipge\.jenkins\jobs\SoapUI-PRO-Allure\workspace\allure-results>exit 0 
Allure Report Generation: started
Allure Report Generation: find directories by mask []
Allure Report Generation: found allure result directories [C:\Users\pulipge\.jenkins\jobs\SoapUI-PRO-Allure\workspace]

Comment: Allure Report Generation: copy founded directories in directory [C:\Users\pulipge\.jenkins\jobs\SoapUI-PRO-Allure\workspace\allure7486688217685518368.tmp\results]
Allure Report Generation: generate report from directory [C:\Users\pulipge\.jenkins\jobs\SoapUI-PRO-Allure\workspace\allure7486688217685518368.tmp]
Allure Report Generation: proxy settings [active:'false', host:'null', port:'0', username:'null', password: '']

Comment: Allure Report Generation: attach report link to build and project
Allure Report Generation: completed
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Vania...I don't think I saw the message in Jenkins that xmls were not found...Can u pls check this output and let me know..Thanks in advance Vania..

Comment: No, it was a wrong statement. I see Jenkins successfully found XML files. Please check that these files have information about tests.